# Bootstrap grid system - how to manage layout when user can hide or show certain elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using bootstrap to develop my web application. I am using grid layout.

I have three divs and I am using following class.

```
<div class = "col-md-5">...</div>
<div class = "col-md-3">...</div>
<div class = "col-md-4">...</div>
```

User can hide or show any of the div. What do I need to do in order to ensure the layout remains correct even when user show or hide certain div. How can I handle this kind of situation.

Comment: Your code is invisible because it isn't formatted as code.

Comment: @BSMP: I updated the formatting. But there is nothing much happening on the code I have shared !!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you may be using `display: none;` to hide the element. This removes the element from the normal page flow, so other elements will try to fill this space and break the layout.

**Quick solution**

Instead of using `display: none;`, you could apply the CSS property `visibility:hidden` to column you want to hide when the user clicks it. This property **hides** the element, but it will still take up the same space as before since it is **not removed from the document flow.**

This way your layout should remain intact even when the column is hidden.